# fundamental group of $S^1$ is isomorphic to fundamental group of $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

How to show fundamental group of $S^1$ is isomorphic to fundamental group of $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ ?

PS: I'm very beginner in algebraic topo. I saw that both of above groups are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ that's why I want to know how set up a direct isomorphism between $\pi_1(S^1)$ and $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}-\{0\})$ without using $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Think about what type of closed curves you can draw in both spaces... I think that is a good start.

Comment: In $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ we can draw any curve that doesn't wind around $\mathbb{0}$ (wlog draawing at $1$) and in $S^1$ wlog taking base point as $1$ we can draw any curves that doesn't comeback to $1$ after any number of complete winds ?

Comment: You can draw curves around 0, they just will not be homotopic to curves that don't wrap around 0. Nor will curves that wrap around different numbers of times. The idea is the same in $S^1$

Answer (score 3):

Homotopy equivalences induce isomorphisms on the fundamental group. In particular, if one space $X$ is a (strong) deformation retract of another space $Y$, we have $\pi_1(X)\cong \pi_1(Y)$. There is a natural deformation retraction $F$ from $\Bbb C - \{0\}$ to the unit circle where $$F(t,z)= t(\frac z{|z|})+(1-t)z $$

This means that the inclusion of the unit circle into $\Bbb C-\{0\}$ is a homotopy equivalence and induces an isomorphism on $\pi_1$.

Answer (score 2):

Since each topological space is arcwise connected it is not important the point you take. We will use the point $(0,1)\in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. For each $\gamma\in \pi(\mathbb{C}-\{0\},(0,1))$ take a represent loop $\alpha\in \gamma$ and define a mapping $\gamma=[\alpha]\mapsto\left[\frac{\alpha}{||\alpha||}\right]$ from $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}-\{0\},(0,1))$ to $\pi_1(S^1,(0,1))$. Prove that this map is an isomorphism.

Comment: can you please show why map is injective ? rest I've done

Comment: Having that $\displaystyle\frac{\alpha}{||\alpha||}\sim\displaystyle\frac{\beta}{||\beta||}$ you will prove that $\alpha\sim\beta$. But $\beta\sim\displaystyle\frac{\beta}{||\beta||}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\alpha}{||\alpha||}\sim \alpha$. Using the properties of the equivalence relation you got $\alpha\sim\beta$ this implies that the function is injective.